# Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas noches comunidad,
Estoy ingresando el desarrollo en android studio y tengo un proyecto el cual eta analizando su estructura y código y al momento de compilar el proyecto me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Mininum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1 Current version is 4.10

He estado investigando sobre ese error pero aún no tengo la idea muy clara de que realizar para corregirlo y poder compilar mi aplicativo.

Estoy trabajando con Android Studii 3.4.1 que según la documentación del proyecto fue en esa versión que se desarrolló.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. El código, los mensajes de error y demás, se añaden como código para facilitar que otros revisen o repliquen tu problema

Comment: Hola Robinson, edité tu pregunta, trata de agregar los textos y código de la IDE como texto ya que como imagen en ocasiones no son visibles para algunos usuarios, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Si actualizaste tu Android Studio a la versión 3.4.0 o mayor, es necesario instalar como minimo la versión 5.4.1 que viene contenida en el Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.4.2**.

Para actualizar ver a :

`File` > `Project Structure` > `Project`

y selecciona la versión 3.4.2 como mínimo del "Android Gradle Plugin Version", esto habilitará la instalación en caso de no estar instalada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para usar gradle 5+ tenes que poner la version del gradle en build gradle (Project) a 3.4.0+ para soportar versiones 5.1.1+

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
```

Podes chequearlo aca

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin